# Using .wav files in wpf without directory

Tags: wpf, wav

Hi I have a wpf application that plays sounds on events such as button click. And the current code I have now plays the sound file, but Ive realized that it has to be in another folder which for example if the user deletes, makes the application pretty much not useable.
I was wondering, How could I get a .wav file without creating a whole new folder in the application Release directory.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the .wav files is added to your project at the root then marked as content (Right Click on the .wav file and click properties. Then change the build action to content) then it will be copied directly to the root output folder

You can the reference the wav file in code or XAML as a relative path (simple "Myfile.wav")

I believe this is what you are asking for?

Comment: Hi, Its build type is already Content. What I am trying to do is to get the sound to be built into the .exe file, and not just as a seperate visible folder that is visible on the clients computer, If you get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the .wav-file as en embedded resource in the dll?

Just add the file to the project, right-click on the file and set *Build Action* to *Embedded Resource*.

Then you can load the .wav file as a stream and save it to disc like this:

```
private void WriteEmbeddedResourceToFile(string writePath, string assemblyName)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream s = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(assemblyName);
        if (s != null)
        {
            var file = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(file, 0, (int)s.Length);
            File.WriteAllBytes(writePath, file);
            s.Close();
        }
    }
```

The string *assemblyName* must be set like this: *namespace.(if you put the file in a folder, insert folder subpath here).filename.wav*

Alternatively, you can drop saving it to disc, and just use the stream directly:

```
private byte[] GetEmbeddedResource(string assemblyName)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream s = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(assemblyName);
        if (s != null)
        {
            var file = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(file, 0, (int)s.Length);
            s.Close();
            return file;
        }
    }
```

Then, when you want to load the file, GetEmbeddedResource will return the byte array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But if i enter this code, How will I then enter my code to play the wav file, as I have a class called MusicPlayer, and to play it the code goes something like:             string file1 = "sounds/ButtonHover.wav";
            List<byte> soundBytes = new List<byte>(File.ReadAllBytes(file1));
            //create media player loading the first half of the sound file
         MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer(soundBytes.ToArray());
            //begin playing the file
            mPlayer.Play();   How can I use your method, while still using my code to play the file?

Comment: Updated post. Use GetEmbeddedResource instead of WriteEmbeddedResourceToFile ;)

Comment: Change your code to:MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer(GetEmbeddedResource(*putAssemblyNameHere*)

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for your reply. Ill try it when I get back from work and ill let you know how it goes. Thanks a lot.